# How to get view of hidden menu?

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

I must implement pop up tooltips in my android app, so I need to get View objects of interesting for me screen elements.

But I have some problem with View from toolbar menu. I need to get an object View menu item, which is shown below.

[image]

Someone knows how to get the object View of this UI element? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the next is not very good, but working way to implement it.

```
int count = mToolbar.getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            View view = mToolbar.getChildAt(i);
            Log.e("View type ", mToolbar.getChildAt(i).getClass().getSimpleName());
            if (view instanceof ActionMenuView) {
                int childCount = ((ActionMenuView) view).getChildCount();
                for (int y = 0; y < childCount; y++) {
                    View overFlowMenuButton = ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(y);
                    Log.e("ActionMenuView type", ((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(y).getClass().getSimpleName());
                    if (overFlowMenuButton.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("OverflowMenuButton")) {

                        Log.e("Need view ", overFlowMenuButton.getClass().getSimpleName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```